# Three quotation levels for csquotes

Tags: punctuation, quoting, nesting, csquotes

The recommended way of solving nested quotations in Norwegian is to use «» for the outer level and then alternating between ‘’ and “”. ([Source](http://www.typografi.org/sitat/sitatart.html))

[image]

Is it a large undertaking to do this with [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Define a new quote style and add appropriate level tests for the outer quotation marks:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[maxlevel=3]{csquotes}

\makeatletter
\DeclareQuoteStyle{threelevel}
    {\ifnum\csq@qlevel<2 \guillemotleft\else\textquotedblleft\fi}% opening outer mark
    {\ifnum\csq@qlevel<2 \guillemotright\else\textquotedblright\fi}% closing outer mark
    {\textquoteleft}% opening inner mark
    {\textquoteright}% closing inner mark
\makeatother

\ExecuteQuoteOptions{style=threelevel}

\begin{document}

\enquote{Jeg (temmelig hånlig): \enquote{I setter uvanlig pris på Dürer --
først kommer \enquote{Som jeg vil fryse etter solen} og nå sanduret fra Melancolia.}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've added two spaces in the definition; while in this case they're not strictly necessary, in other situations they may be crucial. When TeX is looking for a constant, it expands tokens until finding something (unexpandable) which can't be part of a number. So in your initial code, `\guillemotleft` would be expanded before the `\ifnum\csq@qlevel<2` test is performed. Happily, the expansion of `\guillemotleft` doesn't start with a digit: you can guess what would happen. The spaces I added will be ignored.

Comment: @egreg Is it correct that no spaces would be necessary if I had used `\tw@` instead of `2`?

Comment: Correct: `\tw@` is unexpandable and TeX just fetches its value.

Comment: Adding something like `\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»}` in your solution makes it easier to use since you can write `«some text»` instead of `\enquote{some text}`.