# Use guillemets for outer quotes and quotation marks for inner quotes with csquotes

Tags: csquotes

With `csquotes` in the Norwegian language, quotes at the inner level will be displayed with single angle brackets, and with guillemets at the outer level.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\enquote{Guillemets at the outer level, but \enquote{single quotation marks} at the inner level}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a very unusual choice, and I'd like to know where the authors of `csquotes` got this from. I have never seen it in any Norwegian text (although it [does apparently exist](http://www.typografi.org/sitat/sitatart.html)).

The most common way of displaying inner quotes in Norwegian, and the ones mentioned in style handbooks, is either:

1. Use guillemets.
2. Use singe quotation marks (as in American English).

As indicated in me MWE, I'd like to go with option 2 here. This means I need to make `csquotes` use `guillemets` for the outer level, but `quotes` for the inner level. How can I do that?

Comment: Does [Three quotation levels for csquotes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64360) help?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Definitely! But I'd appreciate if someone would provide an answer to my simpler scenario, as I doubt that three levels of quotations would ever be needed (`csquotes` also sets two levels as the max by default).

Comment: If you don't need the fancy three-fold quotation marks, you can go with `\DeclareQuoteStyle[sverre]{norwegian}
  {\guillemotleft}
  {\guillemotright}
  [0.025em]
  {\textquoteleft}
  {\textquoteright}` and `\ExecuteQuoteOptions{norwegian=sverre}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adapt and create new quote styles quite easily using `\DeclareQuoteStyle`

In your case

```
\DeclareQuoteStyle[sverre]{norwegian}
  {\guillemotleft}%  opening outer
  {\guillemotright}% closing outer
  %[0.025em]
  {\textquoteleft}%  opening inner
  {\textquoteright}% closing inner
```

seems appropriate.

I have commented out the middle optional argument, it provides additional kerning if two quotation marks of different quote levels end up adjacent to each other. Choose a value you seem fit.

For a list of available quotation marks see Table 6 on p. 31 of [the `csquotes` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\DeclareQuoteStyle[sverre]{norwegian}
  {\guillemotleft}
  {\guillemotright}
  %[0.025em]
  {\textquoteleft}
  {\textquoteright}

\ExecuteQuoteOptions{norwegian=sverre}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Guillemets at the outer level, but \enquote{single quotation marks} at the inner \enquote{level}}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sure that the current maintainer of `csquotes` would be delighted to receive more detailed information on how quotation marks are usually used in Norwegian texts, can drop him a line at the [github repository](https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes).

Answer (score 4):

You can declare your style using `\DeclareQuoteStyle` and then select it with `\setquotestyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\DeclareQuoteStyle{mystyle}
{\guillemotleft}{\guillemotright}
{\textquoteleft}{\textquoteright}
\setquotestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Guillemets at the outer level, but \enquote{single quotation marks} at the inner level}.
\end{document}
```

[image]